# Missing reference conversion between classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

everyone ! I had a problem with Ninject in Method AddBindings - cannot understand properly what would be better to do to fix this issue :

> Error CS0311  The type 'ClassLibrary1.Concrete.EFGameRepository' cannot
>   be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or
>   method 'IBindingToSyntax.To()'.
>   There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'ClassLibrary1.Concrete.EFGameRepository' to
>   'ClassLibrary1.Abstract.IGameRepository'.

Here is the following code :

```
namespace GameStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private IKernel kernel;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernelParam)
        {
            kernel = kernelParam;
            AddBindings();
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {

            kernel.Bind<IGameRepository>().To<EFGameRepository>();
        }
    }
}
```

EFGameRepository

```
public class EFGameRepository 
{ 
    EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext(); 
    public IEnumerable<Game> Games { get { return context.Games; } } 
}
```

Comment: Please show definition of `EFGameRepository` class

Comment: <code> public class EFGameRepository
    {
        EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();

        public  IEnumerable<Game> Games
        {
            get { return context.Games; }
        }
    }<code>

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue `EFGameRepository` must implement `IGameRepository`

```
public class EFGameRepository : IGameRepository
{
    // implement IGameRepository members implicit or explicit
}
```